# understanding uart registers indexing

Tags: c, cpu-registers, uart

The function below prints out the contents of a UART register. This is the register map.

[uart registers](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wnoWA.png)

Could somebody explain why, the for loop goes up in `+=4`?

Thank you

```
#define UART0_BASE 0x21000

void print_uart(unsigned int base) {
int i;
int val;
unsigned int adr;

  for (i=0; i< 0x18; i+=4) {
    adr = base + i;
    printf("Uart %s [0x%x] -> 0x%x\n",uart_reg[i>>2],adr,val);
  }
}
```

Comment: That looks broken. What processor is it for?

Comment: Addresses of an external peripheral device do not need to be identical on both sides of the "wire".
You might attach `A0..An` of your UART to `A2..An+2` of your CPU/Memory Controller with `A0,A1` being fixed at ground.
This would result in a distance of 4 addresses on CPU side while they are still adjacent on UART side.
As your UART has 16 bit registers each address already represents 2 bytes.

Answer (score 0):

Most likely to fit the start address of each register. Since the for loop runs up to 0x18(24) that makes it 6 registers. It might look like that the registers are only 16 bits but often there's also some padding.

Comment: thanks, maybe a silly question - but if the base address is `0x21000` and the register is 16 bits - how does incrementing 4 get to the next register?

Comment: Well I'm assuming that each register actually takes 32 bits of data. 16 bits of stuff and 16 bits of padding.

So the +=4 represents 4 bytes. 

To jump to the next register you need to jump over the current one. So base 0x21000 is where the Recieve data is, 0x21001 is the reserved byte, 0x21002 is padding, 0x21003 is padding. 0x21004 is the next register

I can't be 100% sure of this as I don't know which processor you're using but if your code works this is most likely the case

Comment: Thank you, I guess your correct. I'm using a NIOS processor which is 32 bit. cheers